# VB6 - Making a new MSAPC.Apc crashes with 'Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface'

Tags: vba, vb6, apc

A VB6 application is being developed.  Internally it uses VBA SDK version 7.1.  The application is an Active X DLL.  When the line of code 'Set Host = New MSAPC.Apc' is executed an exception is thrown.  The exception reads "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface".  Host is a class member defined like this "Public WithEvents Host As Apc".  For all intents and purposes this code should work but does not and I can't find anything resolution.

Comment: what happens with dim host : set host = new MSAPC.Apc

Comment: When I **`Dim Host`** and **`Set Host = CreateObject("MSAPC.Apc")`** I don't get a crash.  That is strange.  Is it possible to still get events?  Is there a AddHandler like in VB.NET?

Comment: Guessing a bit here but it sounds like it thinks 'MSAPC.Apc' and 'As Apc' are different types of thing - maybe with different guids.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select reference as "Microsoft APC 7.1 Object Library" and not "Microsoft APC 6.2 Object Library". This will solve the problem.

Regards,
Anagha